# What is the most efficient/performant way to store and access random text via JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, cordova, random

I'm building a turn-based iPad game using HTML5/jQuery + PhoneGap.

After each turn a player takes, we want to show some random text-based information. Typically a sentence.

In total, we may have about 100 different sentences divided up into 4 groups.

In terms of performance, what would be the proper way to go about this?

Is that amount of content suitable for simply storing in 4 javascript arrays? Or is that too much? If too much, would creating a separate JSON file make more sense? Or using local storage? Or would those be overkill? Or should we just 'store' the 100 bits of text in the HTML DOM and access it from there? Other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to see if you had a performance hit from storing them in memory? I don't expect any issues with 100 sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage and store 25 in one localStorage object separated by any character (e.g. "^") then use split() to access the strings.

```
localStorage.str = "foo^bar^baz"; //etc..
var str1 = localStorage.str;
str1.split("^");
for(var i = 0; i &lt; str.length;i++){
alert(str1[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

100 sentences is trivial and you should not have any performance impact from using arrays, but you can always try it...

http://jsfiddle.net/ZpCfB/ (with 100)

http://jsfiddle.net/ZpCfB/1/ (with 4000)

```
var sentences = [[], [], [], []],
    groupCount = 4,
    i = 0,
    sentence = 'This is a very very very long sentence This is a very very very long sentence This is a very very very long sentence This is a very very very long sentence This is a very very very long sentence This is a very very very long sentence This is a very very very long sentence This is a very very very long sentence This is a very very very long sentence This is a very very very long sentence This is a very very very long sentence This is a very very very long sentence This is a very very very long sentence This is a very very very long sentence This is a very very very long sentence This is a very very very long sentence sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsd sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsd fsdfsdfsdf s.';

for (; i < 25; i++) {
    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        sentences[x].push(sentence);
    }
}

console.log(sentences);
```